# Can I use $$updated when extending a firebase factory to run a getTotal() function like in the example?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Can I receive what is returned by $$updated or have $$updated run a function that I can then receive from every time a task is checked off?

At the end of the day, I need to keep a count of how many tasks users complete. It seems like firebase has ways of automatically syncing that data but it's unclear how to do that specifically. I've run into problems with $watch and running functions when a task is completed. This looks like an interesting way of doing it but I can't put the pieces together.

Here is working plnkr of the code below: http://plnkr.co/edit/iAGvPHFWn2GSPGzBRpKh?p=preview

```
// Code goes here
angular.module('app', ['firebase']);

angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('main', function($scope, $firebase, $timeout, $window, ListWithTotal) {

  var ref = new Firebase("https://plnkr.firebaseio.com");
  $scope.listWithTotal = ListWithTotal(ref);

  $scope.addTask = function(task) {  
    $scope.listWithTotal.$add({
      title: task.title,
      complete: false,  
      tally: 0  
    });
    task.title = ''; 
  };

  $scope.completeTask = function(task) {  
    if (task.complete === true) {
      task.complete = true;
      task.tally = 1;
    } else { 
      task.complete = false;
      task.tally = 0;
    }
    $scope.listWithTotal.$save(task);
  };

  $scope.tallyCount = '';
  //it would be cool if I can get tallyCount to receive 
  //the result of getTotal or automagically with $$updated. 


}).factory("ListWithTotal", ["$FirebaseArray", "$firebase", function($FirebaseArray, $firebase) {
  // create a new factory based on $FirebaseArray
  var TotalFactory = $FirebaseArray.$extendFactory({
    getTotal: function() {
      var total = 0;
      angular.forEach(this.$list, function(rec) {
        total += rec.tally;
      });
      return total;
    },
    $$updated: function(){
      return this.$list.getTotal();
    }
  });
  return function(listRef) {
    var sync = $firebase(listRef, {arrayFactory: TotalFactory});
    return sync.$asArray(); // this will be an instance of TotalFactory
  };
}]);
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want an up-to-date tally of all completed tasks, you can add a `then` to the point where you save the task:

```
$scope.listWithTotal.$save(task).then(function() {
  $scope.tallyCount = $scope.listWithTotal.getTotal();
});
```

The `then` block executes after the task has saved and adds the tally of completed tasks to the current scope.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is the way I am doing it now. There should be a way to tie this functionality to the array directly so that whenever a task is added/removed/changed the update happens automatically on the server/locally. That's what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but this binding in the view works: `completed count: {{listWithTotal.getTotal()}}`

Comment: That would work (probably, in my case I have a series of users but that's unrelated) but I want to see if I can do it by overwriting the $$updated function. It seems like having that functionality inside of the $firebase array would be cleaner and easier to maintain. I will need to do other things like create copies of the tasks and move them to different lists, etc.

Comment: In `{{listWithTotal.getTotal()}}` sample the logic **is** in your FirebaseArray extension. But that return from `$$updated` you do will not end up in your scope, which seems to be what you're expecting. You will *either* have to update the scope (which is what my answer does) *or* bind to the array's method (which is what my previous comment does).

Comment: Yea, I was hoping there would be a way to have an update on the server (running the getTotal function when $$updated is run) trigger an event on $scope that would update that value. {{listWithTotal.getTotal}} would do that but that would constantly run that function from what I understand. Running it only when I complete a task would mean I would need to run it again when a task is moved to incomplete or if a task is deleted – it would create more edge cases I need to account for.